# How to shutdown a Windows 7 PC from Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, windows-7, gnome-terminal

I want to shutdown a Windows 7 PC from my Ubuntu PC, is there a way to do this from terminal?

Comment: Remote desktop can help.

Comment: @mikewhatever is there Remote Desktop "from terminal"?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, that's possible. I don't have any Windows computers available, so I can't test it, but it should be something like this: `net rpc SHUTDOWN -C "Byebye" -f -I IP_ADDRESS -U USER%PASSWORD`, where you obviously replace `IP_ADDRESS`, `USER` and `PASSWORD` with relevant values.

Comment: so does that mean I need his password?

Comment: @AnonymousJohn you always need proper autentification.

Comment: You need to configure Windows for it, you need a user that's _allowed_ to perform remote shutdowns and you must login using proper credentials. Otherwise, it would be a denial of service attack. By the way, you might not want to provide the password in the command line, because that will be logged in your history. If you don't provide it, you'll be prompted to enter it.

Comment: So, I have to actually type in the admin account on his PC and the password into terminal? I don't know his password.

Comment: You don't have to be admin, but you have to have the right to turn off the computer. But did you really expect that Microsoft had designed their operating system so that anyone could turn off any computer at any time without any auth?